# gpupdate causes infinite loop

Tags: active-directory, windows-7, windows-xp, windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy

I've got a patch file with the following content:

```
gpupdate /force /boot /logoff
```

When executing this file it causes an infinite loop, executing the line in the same cmd window again and again. This occurs on a XP 32bit client as well as on a Win 7 64bit client. The Server hosting AD is Server 2008 R2.

How can I solve this issue/improve this script? The script is just for my convenience, it gets executed manually. I want to force the client to update the group policy.

edit: When I type the line in a terminal and execute it the loop will not occur.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because you're trying to reboot and logoff at the same time. Try one or the other. Since a reboot will force a logoff but a logoff won't force a reboot, I would use /Boot instead of /Logoff.

Comment: First, a reboot is only issued when applying the GPO requires a reboot, so if I would use /boot option only, a GPO that needs just a re-login would not be applied. Second, when I type the command line manually in a terminal, the loop does not occur, that's the strange thing...

Comment: I thought using the /Boot parameter forced a reboot regardless?

Comment: According to http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739112%28WS.10%29.aspx it only reboots when necessary. That's also my observation of the tool's behaviour. (I don't think that changed from Server 2003, where the link comes from...)